# How do I make a GET REST API call to my Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple Firebase Realtime database that looks like this:

[image: My simple JSON Todo database]

I created it with a PUT call using this as the body:

```
[{
      "complete": false,
      "editMode": false,
      "title": "Mow the lawn",
      "id": 26,
      "note": "This is a note for 27"
    },

 {
      "complete": true,
      "editMode": false,
      "title": "Feed the dog",
      "id": 27,
      "note": "This is a note for 27"
    }   
]
```

I want to create a REST GET call to get the first item based on the ID (26 in this case).

My rules look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "todos": {
      ".indexOn": ["id"]      
  }  
}
}
```

I tried:

```
https://<myid>.firebaseio.com/todos/26/id.json
```

but that returned `null` because of course that dang '0' and '1' are there.

I can do this:

```
https://<myid>.firebaseio.com/todos/0.json
```

and that returns the first item, but when I do this:

```
https://<myid>.firebaseio.com/todos.json
```

the '0' and the '1' aren't returned, so how do I know to use them?

Do you understand my confusion?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't natively store arrays. Instead it stores the array elements in sequential keys, starting with `"0"`.

When you request a location/query with sequential keys starting with `"0"` through the REST API, Firebase returns the data as an array, which is what you see when you request `todo.json`.

But you can address individual items in the array by their key, which is what you did by requesting `todo/0.json`.

All of the above gets a single node by its complete and absolute path. But it seems that what you want is to retrieve a node by querying for the value of one of its properties. To do that, you'll need to use a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering).

To get the item(s) with `"id"` equal to `26`, you can perform the following query:

```
https://<myid>.firebaseio.com/todos.json?orderBy="id"&equalTo=26
```

Since there may be multiple child nodes under `todos` with `id` equal to `26`, this returns a list of such nodes. In the case of the JSON you shared:

```
{
  "0": {
    "complete": false,
    "editMode": false,
    "id": 26,
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Frank -- thank you for answering my question.  I could have sworn I tried that.  Your solution did exactly what I wanted.  I'm grateful.

Comment: Im not able to achieve above.My rest api is ```https://dth-friend.firebaseio.com/dth-friend.json?orderBy="channelName"&equalTo="Digishala"``` and my response to api is ```{}```

Comment: My rules are {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false,
    "dth-friend": {
      ".indexOn": ["channelName"]
      }
  }
}

Comment: My JSON data is [
 {
   "channelName": "&FLIX",
   "channelNumber": 541,
   "dishProvider": "Dish tv"
 },
 {
   "channelName": "&FLIX HD",
   "channelNumber": 540,
   "dishProvider": "Dish tv"
 }] @NickHodges

Comment: This works though ```https://dth-friend.firebaseio.com/0.json```

Comment: Ok, it works for me now.My data structure was wrong. I added a key for array.

Comment: Any idea how can i add multiple equalTo like channelName = 'abcd' and dishProvider = 'efgh'